# Calculate torque for a cam

Tags: torque

How do you calculate the torque on the cam, with a force placed on the follower?

Two possibilities:

1. Linear cam (schematic)

[image]

2. Radial cam (schematic)

[image]

Comment: You have to state the speed of the cam, esp. if could it cause follower lift off (due to inertia) as that will effect the calculation.

Comment: @PaulUszak The speed of the cam is "v", I am looking for a general solution, hence a symbolic expression.

Comment: Well you could start with a simple statics vector problem using the shallowest incident angle onto the follower and assume a friction less system.  Your major problem will be the friction on the cam holder in the first question.  Where's the applied force in the second question?

Comment: @PaulUszak Could you explain a bit further your though on the shallowest incident angle ? Concerning your questions: The images are only schematic. I am assuming no friction, and for the second camholder, you can imagine a torsional spring attached to the follower, which acts as a counter-force.... but my goal here is not to be specific, I would like to have a general formulation (vector based, if possible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

[image: vectors]

Take the [Angle] that's most prejudicial to opposing F, and consider the lever arm to the camshaft centre.  It looks like my screen grab is the worst case scenario, but with the changing lever arm to point of contact, you should really repeat this for sever angles of cam rotation.  I'm sure there's software for this, but it can be done graphically by hand by plotting a surface development of the cam profile against shaft rotation, say 0 - 180 degrees.  Repeat the calculation every 15 degrees and Fanny's your Aunt.

One thing.  You can't possibly have a fully algebraic solution unless you have an equation for the profile of the cam as you won't be able to determine [Angle] other than by numerical /graphical means.  I might  be tempted to scan the cam profile and use a graphics package to segment and develop the cam profile.  Or use a rule.